# Scrutinizer PHP Analyzer and global composer dependencies

Tags: scrutinizer

Our project depends on the bower asset plugin, which has to be installed globally. The question is how to teach scrutinizer to install it before running PHP Analyzer:

Adding it to dependencies doesn't do the trick. Here is the configuration:

```
build:
    dependencies:
        # Runs before inferred commands
        before:
            - 'composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"'
    tests:
        override:
            - 'vendor/bin/phpunit'

filter:
    excluded_paths:
        - 'vendors/*'
        - '*/vendors/*'
        - '*/tests/*'
        - '*/vendor/*'
tools:
    js_hint:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
    php_mess_detector:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
    php_analyzer:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
        config:
            parameter_reference_check: { enabled: true }
            checkstyle: { enabled: false, no_trailing_whitespace: true, naming: { enabled: true, local_variable: '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$', abstract_class_name: ^Abstract|Factory$, utility_class_name: 'Utils?$', constant_name: '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*$', property_name: '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$', method_name: '^(?:[a-z]|__)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', parameter_name: '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$', interface_name: '^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*Interface$', type_name: '^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$', exception_name: '^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*Exception$', isser_method_name: '^(?:is|has|should|may|supports)' } }
            unreachable_code: { enabled: false }
            check_access_control: { enabled: false }
            typo_checks: { enabled: false }
            check_variables: { enabled: false }
            suspicious_code: { enabled: false, overriding_parameter: false, overriding_closure_use: false, parameter_closure_use_conflict: false, parameter_multiple_times: false, non_existent_class_in_instanceof_check: false, non_existent_class_in_catch_clause: false, assignment_of_null_return: false, non_commented_switch_fallthrough: false, non_commented_empty_catch_block: false, overriding_private_members: false, use_statement_alias_conflict: false, precedence_in_condition_assignment: false }
            dead_assignments: { enabled: false }
            verify_php_doc_comments: { enabled: false, parameters: false, return: false, suggest_more_specific_types: false, ask_for_return_if_not_inferrable: false, ask_for_param_type_annotation: false }
            loops_must_use_braces: { enabled: true }
            check_usage_context: { enabled: true, method_call_on_non_object: { enabled: true, ignore_null_pointer: true }, foreach: { value_as_reference: true, traversable: true }, missing_argument: true, argument_type_checks: lenient }
            simplify_boolean_return: { enabled: false }
            phpunit_checks: { enabled: false }
            reflection_checks: { enabled: false }
            precedence_checks: { enabled: true, assignment_in_condition: true, comparison_of_bit_result: true }
            basic_semantic_checks: { enabled: false }
            doc_comment_fixes: { enabled: false }
            reflection_fixes: { enabled: false }
            use_statement_fixes: { enabled: true, remove_unused: true, preserve_multiple: false, order_alphabetically: false }
    sensiolabs_security_checker:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
    php_cpd:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
    php_pdepend:
        filter:
            excluded_paths: ['vendors/*','*/vendors/*','*/vendor/*','*/tests/*']
        excluded_dirs:
            - vendors
            - vendor

checks:
    php:
        code_rating: true
        duplication: true
```

Here are the Analyzer results

```
Installing vendors through composer ...
+===================================================================================+
| You can avoid this step by committing your composer.lock file to your repository. |
+===================================================================================+
Identity added: /home/scrutinizer/composer-install/../ssh-key0 (/home/scrutinizer/composer-install/../ssh-key0)
Identity added: /home/scrutinizer/composer-install/../ssh-key1 (/home/scrutinizer/composer-install/../ssh-key1)
You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package bower-asset/jquery could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package bower-asset/jquery-ui could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package bower-asset/text could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package bower-asset/requirejs could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package bower-asset/jquery-form could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package bower-asset/jquery-colorbox could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see  for more details.

Read  for further common problems.
```

Comment: Response from Scrutinizer team:  

I'm sorry but we currently do not install composer plugins  for analysis. We have made an internal ticket about this requirement.